# Unable to create Build in titanium

Tags: appcelerator

At the time of debug my titanium application, it always say "failed to run dexer" in console and Build fails. Even i am not able to run very basic app in Appcelerator Titanium. I tried to find the solution here and there but did not get able to solve the issue. Every time i am cleaning the project, restarting the Titanium some time restarting my windows machine also but still facing the same problem. Hoping to have some quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please Goto Project->Clean

Then restart your Titanium Studio. Detach your mobile device from computer and re-attach and wait for 5mins.

If still doesn't work, then goto your RUN->CMD->adb kill-server->adb devices

Comment: Please download the newer version of Titanium Studio and Titanium SDK and try and let me know if it works.

Comment: @sUndeep..it worked for me. Thanks for valuable suggestion. But still digging the the exact solution of this issue. :)

Comment: Please let me know if you find a perfect solution or I will let you know if I find anything good.